# Does Opera work with the global application menu?

Tags: appmenu, opera

I’m curious… Is there a way to get Opera working with the global menu? That would be very nice if it could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Far as I know there is no way currently to integrate Opera with the application menu in the meantime. I searched but I didn't reach to a solution.

Even I've tried using latest opera; [Opera-next](http://www.opera.com/browser/next/) , but It doesn't have support to it.